# How do i disable a single clicked button in an arrays of bootstrap 4 button groups in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a button groups displaying arrays of information, i want to disable one of the list of button when clicked upon. How do i achieve this.

trying to achieve this using angular click event to disable one of the button group when clicked upon.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

    <button type="button" style="height:100px; width: 200px; margin:5px;"  

class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"

 *ngFor="let mysurvey of survey" (click)="getspecificname($event,mysurvey)">

{{mysurvey.category}}</button>

</div>
```

angular 7

```
getspecificname(disablebutton: any , name: any) {

 this.getname = name.category;

 let buttonslenght = this.survey.length - 1;

 let buttonid  = name.questionID;

 for( var i = 0 ; i <=buttonslenght; i++) {

  const getId = this.survey[i].questionID;

  if(getId === buttonid && this.buttonDisabled === false) {

 }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your code properly

Comment: Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Complete Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript referencing for this:

```
getspecificname(disablebutton: any , name: any) {

  name.disabled = true

}
```

The `name` local variable is a reference to the object representing your `button` in the `ngFor`, so you can access the properties as if they were "local".

Then apply this to the button in the same way:

HTML

```
<button type="button" 
  style="height:100px; width: 200px; margin:5px;"  
 class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"
  *ngFor="let mysurvey of survey" 

  [disabled]='mysurvey.disabled'

  (click)="getspecificname($event,mysurvey)">

   {{mysurvey.category}}

 </button>
```